# about gojs, set the desiredSize property of part

Tags: javascript, gojs

The first step, I made a part and initialized the `desiredSize` to `new go.Size(1000, 1000)` and added it under the diagram object. There is no problem here;

The second step is to set the `desiredSize` property of part to `new go.Size(NaN, NaN)`.

Two situations:

1. Perform the first step, then the second step, part disappears.
2. Perform the second step first, the part is infinite; then the first step, then the second step, the part disappears.

What I want to achieve is to set desiredSize to be infinitely large, and the size can be switched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but GoJS does not support a width or a height of Infinity for any GraphObject.

Setting width or height to NaN, which is the default value for both properties, just allows the object to be naturally sized.